# Downloading Dropbox from terminal with wget makes command crash.-UBUNTU SERVER 12.04

Tags: command-line, server, dropbox, wget

I have downloaded Dropbox manually on many instances on Ubuntu systems.
Today I tried to use it on an Ubuntu 12.04 server edition, so I used the command `wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86_64"` in my home directory.
The problem is, the command crashes, at the moment the message `"HTTP request sent, awaiting response"` is last shown, and starts throwing random characters on screen, until I force it to stop.
 Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Note:I'm executing this through putty from a Windows OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `-O -` tells wget to write the file content to stdout (your terminal) instead of saving it to a file.

The actual instructions at https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx, say:

**32-bit:**

```
cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86" | tar xzf -
```

**64-bit:**

```
cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86_64" | tar xzf -
```

which has wget output the file contents (which is a gzipped tar archive) to a pipe with a tar command on the other end. And the tar is told to read a gzipped archive from stdin (`-f -`).

On a side-note, using the debian package is easier.

Comment: Thank you for the notice, I 'm not very familiar with the command line details yet.It's true I didn't follow the instructions bit by bit.I did finally install it with packages, but since this should also work, I wanted to know why this happened and fix it. Again, thank you!

Comment: Small hint: As I learned the other day, you can leave out the `z` from `tar x` commands nowadays: `... | tar xf -` will do just fine.

Comment: @Arne, yes, GNU tar has done that for a fairly long time now, but as far as I know, it only applies to GNU tar. In UNIX and UNIX-like systems that don't have GNU tar, you'll still need the `-z`, assuming the system has a `tar` command at all. It's not a standard unix command, believe it or not. However, Ubuntu does have GNU tar, so this is indeed useful information. I just feel it's important to mention it won't behave the same way on every system you encounter.

Comment: @geirha Yes, thanks for the clarification. I wouldn't have guessed, that `tar` as a command is not part of POSIX. It seems that the file format is a POSIX standard, though. Just wanted to share my new-found information anyway.